# How can I open A Custom ListView Item in A separate Activity?

Tags: java, listview, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have looked through other Posts as much as I can, and though this may be a simple problem, for the life of me I can't figure out how to make this work. I have a Database of Customers, including their names, address, etc.

I would Like to be able to select one of the customers from my custom ListView, and View all of their Database information in A separate Activity. Currently, I cant make it give me anything past the first record.

Any advice would be very helpful if you can see what I am doing wrong.
I am fairly new to Java so Please take it easy on me :P My best guess right now is that I need to create a new cursor but I'm a bit lost.

Code attached below.

Database Viewer.java

```
public class DatabaseViewer extends AppCompatActivity{

TextView DisplayName;
TextView DisplayID;
TextView DisplayMarks;
TextView DisplayAddress;
DatabaseHelper mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
ListView customerlist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_database_viewer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    customerlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCustomers);

    populateDatabase();
    customerlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
            DisplayID = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.TVCUSTOMERNAME);
            DisplayMarks = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.TVADDRESS);
            DisplayName = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.TVID);
            DisplayAddress = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.TVMARKS);

            // NEED TO MAKE A CURSOR THAT GETS ALL ROWS NOT COLUMNS LIKE BELOW.
            int c1 = mydb.getallrows().getPosition();
            // 35 ROWS 4 COLUMNS.

            String item = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(i));


            Intent clientViewIntent = new Intent(DatabaseViewer.this, ClientViewer.class);

            clientViewIntent.putExtra("Client ID", c1);
            startActivity(clientViewIntent);
        }
    });
}

private void populateDatabase(){
    Cursor c = mydb.getallrows();
    customerlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCustomers);
    String[] fromfieldnames = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.COL_1, DatabaseHelper.COL_2, DatabaseHelper.COL_3, DatabaseHelper.COL_4};
    int[] tofieldnames = new int[] {R.id.TVCUSTOMERNAME, R.id.TVADDRESS, R.id.TVMARKS, R.id.TVID};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.custom_db_viewer_row, c, fromfieldnames, tofieldnames, 0);
    customerlist.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void OnClientLongPress(){
    // Function to Open up Client Information in a new activity.
    // Step 1, Use data from Client to pull up Full Client Records.
    // Step 2, Send Data in Intent Extras.
    Intent clientVIewIntent = new Intent(DatabaseViewer.this, ClientViewer.class);
    clientVIewIntent.putExtra("Client ID", customerlist.getSelectedItemId());
    startActivity(clientVIewIntent);
}
```

ClientViewer.java

```
  public class ClientViewer extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_viewer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_invoice_creator);

        Bundle NameIntentData = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (NameIntentData==null){
            return;
        }
        int IntentDataID = NameIntentData.getInt("Client ID");
        String IntentDataName = NameIntentData.getString("Client Name");
        String IntentDataAddress = NameIntentData.getString("Client Address");

        final TextView IDBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ClientViewerIDTV);
        final TextView Namebar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ClientViewerNameTV);
        final TextView AddressBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ClientViewerAddressTV);

        Namebar.setText(Integer.toString(IntentDataID));
        IDBar.setText(IntentDataName);
        AddressBar.setText(IntentDataAddress);

    }
}
```

Thanks so much for your time and effort guys. Really cant wait to hear back from you.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "OnItemClickListener didn't work for me?"

Comment: anyone got any further Ideas? perhaps as to How I can get Client Id onclick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView textview =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvInVisitorName)).getText().toString();
```

Use this on onClick and get your text view data like this.

Comment: Thanks Again Friend, Perfect awnser. I will try this and let you know how it goes. You have been more than helpful. I tried something like that earlier but I didnt initialise in the onclick. Thanks again!

Comment: Have tried to use this fix, through this method                 String t = DisplayID.getText().toString();
                
                // NEED TO MAKE A CURSOR THAT GETS ALL ROWS NOT COLUMNS LIKE BELOW.
                // 35 ROWS 4 COLUMNS.
                
                Intent clientViewIntent = new Intent(DatabaseViewer.this, ClientViewer.class);

                clientViewIntent.putExtra("Client ID", t); Only Now I seem to be getting ID 1 consistently

Comment: You can approve my answer too if my answer helped you

Answer (score 0):

Get the ID of client onClick which is same and unique as stored in DB
Then, pass it to another activity
Pass id parameter and get all the data based on that ID and display..don't pass all the data via intent just pass one key and get all data and display

Hope this will help you

Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks Anamica! I have tried doing that as well, through this method                                                     

 clientViewIntent.putExtra("Client ID", customerlist.getItemIdAtPosition(1));

and It always gives me the number 0 for some reason. any Ideas there?

Comment: Have also tried methods such as
  clientViewIntent.putExtra("Client ID", customerlist.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString()); with no success

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, Largely in thanks to Anamica!

The code

```
String a = Long.toString(l);

Intent clientViewIntent = new Intent(DatabaseViewer.this, 
ClientViewer.class);

clientViewIntent.putExtra("Client ID", a);
startActivity(clientViewIntent);
```

Got me where I needed to be.(Shows the Id of Item) Thanks again Guys!